# Find symbols in disassembly of exe file using llvm-objdump

Tags: windows, clang, exe, debug-symbols, objdump

I'm compiling a program on windows using cmake and clang-cl with flags `/Zi` and `/DEBUG:FULL`. I can step through the program using VS code and it shows function names in the call stack.
However, when I try to disassemble with llvm-objdump, I get the whole .txt as a single block, no function names whatsoever. I want to check the disassembly of a single function but llvm-objdump says `failed to disassemble missing function <name>`. How can I make llvm-objdump recognize the exe symbols.

P.S. I'm familiar with linux and ELF but not really with EXE format, that's why I'm using clang instead of msvc.